# Pascal - Program hangs upon form switching

Tags: forms, pascal, lazarus

I am currently developing a simple application to count the number of clicks within 10 seconds, read in names and scores from two different files, then display those names and scores with various sorts in another form. However, after the game is finished, the 'Game Over!' message appears, the Leaderboard form appears but then has no buttons, looks oddly flat and appears to crash the program.

This is how the form should look:
[Leaderboard Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwAVD.png)

And this is how it actually looks: [Leaderboard Error in Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fCtb.png)

Code for displaying the form can be found below:

```
if TimeLeft=0 then
     begin
          Form2.Timer1.Enabled:=False;{Disable timer}
          ShowMessage('Game Over!');{Message to show upon termination condtion being met}
          Leaderboard.Show;{Show Leaderboard Form}
          Form2.Hide;{Hide game}
          Reset(LeaderboardNamesFile);{Open file}
          while not EOF(LeaderboardNamesFile) do
                LineCount:=LineCount+1;{Increment to allow for EOF marking of the score}
          LeaderboardScoresArray[LineCount]:=Score;{Add score to array of scores}
     end;
```

And the code contained in the Score display button on the Leaderboard form:

```
var Counter : Integer;
begin
     Counter:=1;
     Memo1.Lines.add(LeaderboardNamesArray[Counter]+' - '+IntToStr(LeaderboardScoresArray[Counter]));
end;
```

I find this all very strange, as nothing actually runs when the form is shown, so it should crash before this if ever, and no crash messages appear. Any ideas? If more info if needed, please ask. New on this site!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The while loop is endless, the loop contains only one command:

```
while not EOF(LeaderboardNamesFile) do
            LineCount:=LineCount+1;{Increment to allow for EOF marking of the score}
```

So, your program count LineCount up but don't aktually read any data from the file. So the file never becomes EOF ("end of file"). You need to do something like this:

```
Reset(LeaderboardNamesFile);{Open file}
while not EOF(LeaderboardNamesFile) do
begin
    LineCount:=LineCount+1;{Increment to allow for EOF marking of the score}
    readln(LeaderboardNamesFile, Score);
    LeaderboardScoresArray[LineCount]:=Score;{Add score to array of scores}
end;
CloseFile(LeaderboardNamesFile);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this read the name into the Score variable? I'm confused as to how this helps. I'm actually more confused that there is someone who still codes in Pascal!

Comment: @Syla: Many people code in Pascal. Most of them in Delphi or FreePascal, but also in other Pascal versions. Please read the answer again: if you don't read anything, EOF will *never* become true, so the loop never stops. `EOF`stands for "end of file" and that can only be reached if you actually read from the file. So either use another criterion to stop the loop, or remove the loop altogether, or well, actually read something from the file until you reach its end, as the answer shows.